# How can I know which system is easier to control using PID controller?

Tags: control, pid, stability

I have a inverted inertia wheel pendulum.
I suppose that if I have a wheel with larger inertia at its top, the system would be more stable.

How can I prove or disprove my conjecture?

Answer (score 2):

Linearize the system around the operating point you're interested in. Look at the eigenvalues of the A and B matrices that represents the linearized system. Then compare the eigenvalues using from systems with different wheel sizes.

Comment: Should I include the PID controller block into the system which is going to be linearized?

Comment: I think that should be a separate question. Come back once you have the linearized equations.

Comment: Could you also work out the physics to create the state-space representation, convert that to a transfer function and then observe the root locus plots?

Comment: A nice resource on the argument: http://www.mne.ksu.edu/static/nlc/tiki-index.php?page=S_H_InertiaWheelPendulum.